# Using Import wizard to import Excel data into table in SQL Server 2012 failing - text truncation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, excel-2010, sql-import-wizard

I have an Excel file that I import weekly into a table.

I am using Excel 2010 and SSMS 2012.  The import failed this week and I have been unable to determine why.  I was able to successfully import the data into a new table.  The table definitions of the new table match the ones of my old table, so that does not seem to be the issue.  Below is a screen shot of the error I receive.  I have checked the PO header text field and there is nothing that exceeds the datatype of varchar(255) that I have it as.

Also, I sorted the data just to see if a certain row was causing the issue and more data did insert, but I still got the error and it was not on the same row as the original import attempt.  I even dropped and created the original table again and I still receive the error.

[image]

Comment: How did you check the length of the columns? If not truncating, could it be the other option it gives you, that you have some strange characters in there? Could try changing the column in the destination table to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: If that were the case, why would the new table give the column varchar(255) when using the import wizard?  I also did a len() in Excel on that column and did not receive anything above 100 characters.

Comment: @tsqln00b Simple test sort rows by text column descending in Excel file, save and run. If it work it means that in your first 8 records there were only short text and type recognition fails.

Comment: That worked.  I never had to do that before, but I will do it from now on.  I hate Excel!

Comment: @tsqln00b I've had exactly the same case once and from that point I know :)

Comment: I'm still confused then as to why, using the same file, I was able to create a new table that had the same data type as my original table and it imported just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 255 is just the default length it picks - doesn't mean there isn't anything longer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably the way how `Import/Export Wizard` or `SSIS` get metadata about datatypes.

It uses first few rows. If there is a long string (longer than 255) then datatype is memo, otherwise is string.

One workaround is to sort Excel rows based on length on text column descending.

> From [Excel Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/excel-source)
>
> **Truncated text.**
>
> **When the driver determines that an Excel column contains text data, the driver selects the data type (string or memo) based on the longest value that it samples. If the driver does not discover any values longer than 255 characters in the rows that it samples, it treats the column as a 255-character string column instead of a memo column.**
>
> **Therefore, values longer than 255 characters may be truncated To import data from a memo column without truncation, you must make sure that the memo column in at least one of the sampled rows contains a value longer than 255 characters, or you must increase the number of rows sampled by the driver to include such a row.**
>
> You can increase the number of rows sampled by increasing the value of TypeGuessRows under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel registry key. For more information, see PRB: Transfer of Data from Jet 4.0 OLEDB Source Fails w/ Error.